# How to handle grails gsp safely in big projects

Tags: jquery, grails, gsp

In my current grails project often `Row was updated and deleted by another transaction` exception is rising, this is because if two or more user trying to access the same content will give a way to rise this exception.

**After debug** the controllers return the values without any problem only gsp rendering taking the time and this rendering acting as a root for this exception

**Question 1** Is there any safe way to handle this gsp rendering?

**Question 2** Is there any jQuery way to wait the second user to wait for page rendering?

**Question 3** How I can write a simple and safe gsp?

**Edit**: During this course there is no save or update operations

please help

Comment: Did you try withTransaction in your controller?

Comment: No i didn't, If you don't mind,can you please brief how it will help me?

Comment: I think (I don't know exactly) `Row was updated and deleted by another transaction` is a message from hibernate, optimistic locking in action. And withTransaction will create new hibernate session. I can be wrong :)

Comment: Yes that is solution if we are updating or saving something, here just I am get the items from db

Comment: Make sure that your are making all the database changes only in the services layer. I can help you more if you provide some code samples.

Comment: You can use @Synchronized at method and all will be set.

Comment: @user593644 those are something confidential, if you can share your mail id, i can forward you the code, or just send a test mail to suganthanchandrika@gmail.com, thank you